# Why can't I send HTTP requests to my Django server running in a docker image on Windows when I can send them to the same exact server setup on Mac?

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Django server built with docker-compose and I am trying to send HTTP requests to it.  When the docker image is built and running on Mac, I can send HTTP requests to the host machine's IP address both from the host machine and from other machines on the same network.  However, when the same docker image is built and running on Windows, I can only send HTTP requests to the host machine's IP address using the host machine.  Other computers on the network don't get a response when sending HTTP requests to the host machine's IP address.  I can also successfully ping the host machine from a different computer on the network.

I have environment variables for the app and for the database that docker-compose brings in from two files (.env.prod and .env.db.prod), and the variables in both files are all the same for both builds of the docker image on Mac and Windows, except for the ALLOWED_HOSTS environment variable which I have set to the IP address of the docker image's host machine.  I have verified that the ALLOWED_HOSTS variable in the server settings is being set with the IP address from the file because when I print the variable during runtime it prints the IP address from the file.

docker-compose.prod.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn EchoNine.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:80
    ports:
      - 80:80
    env_file: .env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file: .env.db.prod
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Dockerfile.prod:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7.4-alpine

# set work directory
ARG PROJECT=EchoNine
ARG PROJECT_DIR=/var/www/${PROJECT}
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR
WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    && pip install psycopg2 \
    && pip install django \
    && pip install djangorestframework \
    && pip install gunicorn \
    && apk del build-deps

# Copy your application code to the container (make sure you create a .dockerignore file if any large files or directories should be excluded)
COPY . $PROJECT_DIR/

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/EchoNine/docker-entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.prod.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

exec $@
```

I would expect the same docker image code to build and run the same way on both operating systems and I would expect to be able to send HTTP requests from other computers on the same network and get responses regardless of what OS the host is running.  How do I solve this problem?